# Oracle - need to extract text between given strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, substring

Example - need to extract everything between "Begin begin"  and "End end". I tried this way:

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, World!End end It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)([[:print:]]+)(End end[[:print:]]+)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

Result: Hello, World!

However it fails if my text contains new line characters. Any tip how to fix this to allow extracting text containing also new lines?

[edit]How does it fail:

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, 
  World!End end It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)([[:print:]]+)(End end[[:print:]]+)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

Result:

> stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,    World!End end It has
>   everything!

Should be:

> Hello,
>    World!

[edit]

Another issue. Let's see to this sample:

```
WITH phrases AS (
  SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,
 World!End end It has everything!End endTESTESTESTES' AS phrase
    FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phrase, '.+Begin begin(.+)End end.+', '\1', 1, 1, 'n')
  FROM phrases;
```

Result:

> Hello,
>   World!End end It has everything!

So it matches last occurence of end string and this is not what I want. Subsgtring should be extreacted to first occurence of my label, so result should be:

> Hello,
>   World!

Everything after first occurence of label string should be ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: How does it fail? Where can you put in a `\n` and break it?

Comment: Interesting problem. I can't work out the solution but I'm watching for who does. :)

Comment: While Stephan and David Faber have a nice solution, it pays to see how others have addressed variations of the new line character in general as it pertains to regular expression in Oracle. I find it informative to see how @APC did this here, stackoverflow.com/questions/16407135/…

Answer (score 6):

I'm not that familiar with the POSIX `[[:print:]]` character class but I got your query functioning using the wildcard `.`. You need to specify the `n` match parameter in `REGEXP_REPLACE()` so that `.` can match the newline character:

```
WITH phrases AS (
  SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,
 World!End end It has everything!' AS phrase
    FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phrase, '.+Begin begin(.+)End end.+', '\1', 1, 1, 'n')
  FROM phrases;
```

I used the `\1` backreference as I didn't see the need to capture the other groups from the regular expression. **It might also be a good idea to use the `*` quantifier (instead of `+`) in case there is nothing preceding or following the delimiters.** If you want to capture all of the groups then you can use the following:

```
WITH phrases AS (
  SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,
 World!End end It has everything!' AS phrase
    FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phrase, '(.+Begin begin)(.+)(End end.+)', '\2', 1, 1, 'n')
  FROM phrases;
```

**UPDATE** - FYI, I tested with `[[:print:]]` and it doesn't work. This is not surprising since `[[:print:]]` is supposed to match *printable* characters. It doesn't match anything with an ASCII value below 32 (a space). You need to use `.`.

**UPDATE #2 - per update to question** - I don't think a regex will work the way you want it to. Adding the lazy quantifier to `(.+)` has no effect and Oracle regular expressions don't have lookahead. There are a couple of things you might do, one is to use `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()`:

```
WITH phrases AS (
  SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,
 World!End end It has everything!End endTESTTESTTEST' AS phrase
    FROM dual
)
SELECT SUBSTR(phrase, str_start, str_end - str_start) FROM (
    SELECT INSTR(phrase, 'Begin begin') + LENGTH('Begin begin') AS str_start
         , INSTR(phrase, 'End end') AS str_end, phrase
      FROM phrases
);
```

Another is to combine `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()` with a regular expression:

```
WITH phrases AS (
  SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello,
 World!End end It has everything!End endTESTTESTTEST' AS phrase
    FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(phrase, 1, INSTR(phrase, 'End end') + LENGTH('End end')), '.+Begin begin(.+)End end.+', '\1', 1, 1, 'n')
  FROM phrases;
```

Comment: 'n' is the key as a matter of fact to ignore new lines

Comment: I actually don't want to ignore new lines. I need to extract untouched text between known strings.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed your soultion work as I need, there is new line in resulting string,

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
([[:print:]]+Begin begin)(.+?)(End end[[:print:]]+)
```

#### Sample usage:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
         phrase ,
         '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)(.+?)(End end[[:print:]]+)',
         '\2',
         1,  -- Start at the beginning of the phrase
         0,  -- Replace ALL occurences
         'n' -- Let dot meta character matches new line character
)
FROM
  (SELECT 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, '
    || chr(10)
    || ' World!End end It has everything!' AS phrase
  FROM DUAL
  )
```

The dot meta character (`.`) matches any character in the database character set and the new line character. However, when regexp_replace is called, the match_parameter must contain `n` switch for `dot` matches new lines.

Comment: No change. Still entire string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your second option to work you need to add `[[:space:][:print:]]*` as follows:

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, 
  World!End end It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)([[:print:]]+[[:space:][:print:]]*)(End end[[:print:]]+)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

But still it will break if you have more `\n`, for instance it won't work for

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, 
  World!End end 
  It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)([[:print:]]+[[:space:][:print:]]*)(End end[[:print:]]+)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

Then you need to add

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. Begin beginHello, 
  World!End end 
  It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Begin begin)([[:print:]]+[[:space:][:print:]]*)(End end[[:print:]]+[[:space:][:print:]]*)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

The problem of regex is that you might have to scope the variations and create a rule that match all of them. If something falls out of your scope, you'll have to visit the regex and add the new exception.

You can find extra info [here](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html).

Comment: I have large text and it can contain many new lines. I need to extract substring from it. So is there any universal solution to do this?

Comment: Normally by adding the `[[:space:][:print:]]*` on each potential place where you can find a new line can help, what you are saying with this line is that "you might find an space or new line and letters" that's what the `*` is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Description.........: This is a function similar to the one that was available from PRIME Computers
                       back in the late 80/90's.  This function will parse out a segment of a string
                       based on a supplied delimiter.  The delimiters can be anything.
Usage:
     Field(i_string     =>'This.is.a.cool.function'
          ,i_deliiter   => '.'
          ,i_start_pos  => 2
          ,i_occurrence => 2)

     Return value = is.a
```

---

```
FUNCTION field(i_string           VARCHAR2
              ,i_delimiter        VARCHAR2
              ,i_occurance        NUMBER DEFAULT 1
              ,i_return_instances NUMBER DEFAULT 1) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  --
  v_delimiter      VARCHAR2(1);
  n_end_pos        NUMBER;
  n_start_pos      NUMBER := 1;
  n_delimiter_pos  NUMBER;
  n_seek_pos       NUMBER := 1;
  n_tbl_index      PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  n_return_counter NUMBER := 0;
  v_return_string  VARCHAR2(32767);
  TYPE tbl_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  tbl tbl_type;
  e_no_delimiters EXCEPTION;
  v_string VARCHAR2(32767) := i_string || i_delimiter;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      ----------------------------------------
      -- Search for the delimiter in the
      -- string
      ----------------------------------------
      n_delimiter_pos := instr(v_string, i_delimiter, n_seek_pos);
      --
      IF n_delimiter_pos = length(v_string) AND n_tbl_index = 0 THEN
        ------------------------------------------
        -- The delimiter you are looking for is
        -- not in this string.
        ------------------------------------------
        RAISE e_no_delimiters;
      END IF;
      --
      EXIT WHEN n_delimiter_pos = 0;
      n_start_pos := n_seek_pos;
      n_end_pos   := n_delimiter_pos - n_seek_pos;
      n_seek_pos  := n_delimiter_pos + 1;
      --
      n_tbl_index := n_tbl_index + 1;
      -----------------------------------------------
      -- Store the segments of the string in a tbl
      -----------------------------------------------
      tbl(n_tbl_index) := substr(i_string, n_start_pos, n_end_pos);
    END LOOP;
    ----------------------------------------------
    -- Prepare the results for return voyage
    ----------------------------------------------
    v_delimiter := NULL;
    FOR a IN tbl.first .. tbl.last LOOP
      IF a >= i_occurance AND n_return_counter < i_return_instances THEN
        v_return_string  := v_return_string || v_delimiter || tbl(a);
        v_delimiter      := i_delimiter;
        n_return_counter := n_return_counter + 1;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    --
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_no_delimiters THEN
      v_return_string := i_string;
  END;
  RETURN TRIM(v_return_string);
END;
```